# How to inflate another view into LinearLayout?

Tags: android, graph, android-linearlayout, android-inflate, layout-inflater

This is my XML with 2 `LinearLayouts`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have downloaded GraphView from http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview. This class extends View. I basically want to initialize 2 graphs via

```
String[] verlabels = new String[]{"aim", "25%", "50%", "75%", "start"};
String[] horlabels = new String[]{"this", "max"};

float[] values = new float[]{2.0f, 6.0f};
aaaGraphView graphView = new aaaGraphView(this, values, "Graph One",
        horlabels, verlabels, aaaGraphView.BAR);

float[] values2 = new float[]{1.0f, 12.0f};
aaaGraphView graphView2 = new aaaGraphView(this, values2, "Graph Two",
        horlabels, verlabels, aaaGraphView.BAR);
```

and then to inflate `graphView` into `ll_one`, and `graphView2` into `ll_two`.

How should I do this? I have initialized the `LinearLayout`

```
   llOne = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_one);
```

but it does not have `inflate()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to `inflate` another `view` inside your `LinearLayout` you'll just have to add another child inside that `LinearLayout`. Just use the [`addView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method on the `LinearLayout` that fits you the best. Here is an example :

```
   llOne.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the name of your class which extends View is aaaGraphView try this:

```
<package1.package2....aaaGraphView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</package1.package2....aaaGraphView>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

try this way i have added the linearlayout into another linear layout this way,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ll_one);
vg.addView(graphView);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's much simpler to do it via addView() method.

Comment: simpler method means what i dont get it? you wanna make it complex?

Comment: I already initialized ll_one as LinearLayout and you introduced another step `final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ll_one);`. Your answer is good as well and that's why I up voted it.

Comment: i really dont mind anything when i am at learning..this is just to share that in my current project i have made one headerfooter.xml and adding each activity layout in the middle linear layout like this : "ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
  ViewGroup.inflate(ShowListAlbumVideos.this, R.layout.newlayout, vg);" so i suggested the same to you..if you find any other then i can also use that.